# FCKeditor extra unwanted slashes coming

Tags: fckeditor

When I try to save text using FCKeditor, too many extra unwanted slashes gets added to the text saved in database.
thanks in adveance for any solution,suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a `phpinfo()` and see if magic quotes are enabled - thats what it sounds like. If they are enabled (shame on your host) then you can make a php.ini file in the directory and put in the lines:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

and that should fix you right up. You may need to use a .htaccess file depending on your webhost setup, in which case you'd use the line:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. It gives me error 500 internal server error and web site doesnt load.. :(

Comment: ok.. the only solution worked for me was, I have to request web hosting providers, to disable magic quotes.... and now it works all fine...

Erik, the solutions provided by you were correct(on php.net found same solns ), but don't know some how it doesn't override the settings done by hosting providers

Thanks :)

Comment: some hosts disable for .htacess and .ini files for "security" reasons, although there are ways to make a host safe without doing so. Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: ok for further readers of this post..

Unwanted slashes added by magic_quotes, can be removed after retrieving data from database using stripslashes(). The php function
stripslashes() while displaying content removes extra slashes which are added to escape single quotes, & all.. (refer php Manual)

Answer (score 0):

Please use PHP's `stripslashes` function

```
stripslashes($content);
```